# Better way to get data from multiple mongo collections using minimongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor, minimongo

I am currently creating a web app in Meteor. This app uses MongoDb and when making queries from the client, it uses minimongo to interact with the underlying mongoDb.

I have 2 collections defined below

```
const chats = {
      userIds: [],
      //other data irrelevant to question
    };

const users = {
          userId: string,
          username: string
          //other data irrelevant to question
        };
```

So basically, the chat collection contains the unique user id's for all the users in the chat and the users collection contains all the users in the system. I am trying to query for all the usernames of the users in a single chat document.

Currently I am achieving this by first querying for all the user id's in a single chat, then using javascript to iterate over those user id's to find their corresponding usernames like so:

```
var thisChat = Chats.findOne(this.chatId); //get current chat document
          var userList = thisChat.userIds; //get list of user id's from this chat      

          this.newUserList = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < userList.length; i++) { //iterate over user id's
              var tempUser = Meteor.users.find({_id: userList[i]}).fetch(); //find username for this userId
              this.newUserList.push(tempUser[0]); //add this username to an array
            }
          });
        });

    return this.newUserList; //return list of usernames
```

This method is pretty ugly, so I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this using minimongo (some kind of join equivalent?). I've looked at other posts that have used populate or aggregate, but these are not available in minimongo.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do this at the server level with the [serverTransform package](https://github.com/maximummeteor/server-transform).

```js
Meteor.publishTransformed('currentChat', function() {
      return Chats.find()
        .serverTransform({
            'usernames': function(chat) {
              return Meteor.users.find({
                _id: {
                  $in: chat.userIds
                }
              }).map(function(user) {
                  return user.username;
                }
              }
            });
        });
```

Now you can just get it from the object itself.

```
var thisChat = Chats.findOne(this.chatId);
var usernames = thisChat.usernames;
```

Another popular package is [publish-composite](https://github.com/englue/meteor-publish-composite)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the users and the chats on the clients then you can use the `$in:` operator in your find followed by a `.map()` to avoid all the looping and pushing.

```
const usernames = Meteor.users.find(
  { _id: { $in: Chats.findOne(this.chatId).userIds }}
  ).map(doc => doc.username);
```